# How to clear queued email messages so they don't send

Tags: cron, order-email, magento2.4.2, magento-cron, message-queue

While moving from M1 to M2 a number of sales-related emails are generated and stack up in the queue. I don't want these messages to be sent to customers regarding "old" orders. How can I clear out the email queue without the cron job sending them?

I've googled around, looked in SE, and even unsuccessfully hit up Magento support and can't find a way to do this...

The closest I've found is this: [Magento2.2.2 Order email confirmation after switched back on sends old order confirmation email](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/324533/magento2-2-2-order-email-confirmation-after-switched-back-on-sends-old-order-con)
but at some point, I need to turn async. sending back on, so I'm right back in the same place...or am I misunderstanding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento 2 does not "queue" up emails as much as mark orders for which emails need to be sent, or not sent.

Instead of a distinct database table to "queue up" outgoing email messages, etc. the data points `send_email` and `email_sent` are included with the `sales_order` table and are used to queue and maintain status for email notifications.

To process the "email queue" Magento sends off emails to entities where the `email_sent` value is null. Finding and changing these records to indicate that they've already sent their emails will prevent them from being sent.

This is more fully explained here: [How does asynchronous email sending works in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198779/how-does-asynchronous-email-sending-works-in-magento-2).